# Editing Long Conditional Formatting Formulas in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Is there a better way to edit conditional formatting formulas in excel then using the short and awkward formula field available by default?

My formula is longer than the field supplied, and the left and right arrows automatically change cell references instead of moving my cursor in the field, so I cannot actually see the all of the formula I am trying to edit.  Is there a better way to do the editing?

Here's the formula (not really looking for a better formula, just a better way to put it into the formula field for my conditional format rule):

```
=AND(OR(COUNT($B$5:$B$22)<2, COUNTIF($B$5:$B$22, B3), IF(B4="C",1,0)))
```

Comment: My workaround is to enter the formula in an empty cell, check if it works OK and then copy it to CF rule.

Answer (score 4):

Just press F2 after left-click into the edit field. This starts the edit mode so you can use the coursor to move forth and back the formular for editing